# How do I put a logo saved in assets directory in my pdf using PDFmake?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, assets, pdfmake

I'm trying to use pdfmake for the first time in an angular project and I need to put a logo on the pdf. I have this logo saved in assets/images directory in the project, is there a way I can read the image from there?

My project's structure is something like this:

```
-app
  --components
-assets
  --images
    ---logo.png
```

I was trying it this way:

```
content: [
    {
      image: require('../../../assets/images/logo.png'),
    }]
```

But it gives me this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Invalid image: TypeError: filename.indexOf is not a function
> Images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

How can I put that logo on my pdf?
Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this. this will work fine. and don't forget to vote up

```
getBase64ImageFromURL(url) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var img = new Image();
  img.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");

  img.onload = () => {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    resolve(dataURL);
  };

  img.onerror = error => {
    reject(error);
  };

  img.src = url;
});
```

}

```
async createPdf() {
var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    
    
    {
      image: await this.getBase64ImageFromURL(
        "../../assets/ribbonLogo1.png"
      )
    }  ,
```